# How to get the names of all files in a directory programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get all files from directory, but i am getting all file types except from .zip, .apk.

```
   val fileDir = File(folder)
   val files = fileDir.list() ?: return null
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You do not have access to all files for many directories on external storage, such as `Documents/` and `Downloads/`.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I need to get files from Downloads/. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: You only have access to files in `Downloads/` via filesystem APIs for files that your app placed there and certain media types.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

You can access the entire directory tree using the code below

**Kotlin**

```
fun openDirectory(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker when it loads.
        putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, your-request-code)
}
```

**Java**

```java
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
    // the system file picker when it loads.
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);

    startActivityForResult(intent, your-request-code);
}
```

to learn more, [checkout](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#kotlin)